# RecyclerView in ConstraintLayout is not showing properly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I tested this `xml` with chaining, `Guideline` and `Barrier` but none of them could help.

The `xml` code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout         
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".RatingActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/welcomeTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="74dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="79dp"
        android:gravity="clip_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/welcome"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/recyclerView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="467dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/submitButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submitButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="@string/submit"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

When it runs on an `AVD`, the `RecyclerView` takes more space than what is needed causing it to cover or push back either `welcomeTextView` or `submitButton`.

BTW, this is the `Gradle` dependency:

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/welcomeTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="74dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="79dp"
        android:gravity="clip_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="welcome"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/welcomeTextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/submitButton" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submitButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="submit"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The only change is set the top of your RecyclerView instead the bottom of your text, and then set the RecyclerView height to 0 and set the `app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"` to enable the height calculation based on constraints. If the welcome message bottom margin doesn't work, try to set a top margin to the RecyclerView.

Comment: Give that man a medal.  Awesome answer.  Saved me a load of time