# RecyclerView cell wrap_content not working with ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

## Expect

The RecyclerView's cell layout of type ConstraintLayout to expand to the display's width and rendered content's height.

*post_cell.xml*

```xml
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/postImage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/post_image_alt"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="@string/feed_image_ratio"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic" />
...
```

This layout implementation works as expected for the *post_cell.xml* in the *[CameraXFeed](https://github.com/AdamSHurwitz/CameraXFeed#-cameraxfeed)* open-source app.

[image: CameraXFeed image]

## Observe

Using the same RecyclerView cell layout above, does not expand to the parent view display's width and rendered content's height in the code outlined below. The RecyclerView displays as empty despite the data being bound in the ViewHolder.

**The issue is isolated to the layout, as the log below in *FeedAdapter.kt* displays the expected photo image URLs in `bind` of the ViewHolder.**

## Implement

*build.gradle*

```
dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3"
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
}
```

The layout design is the same as in the *Expect* section.

*photo_cell.xml*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="@dimen/card_elevation"
    android:focusable="true">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:translationZ="0dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/postImage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/photo_image_alt"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="@string/feed_image_ratio"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

The Android Studio Design preview confirms the layout should work as described in the *Expect* section.

[image: Android Studio Design view]

*fragment_feed.xml*

```kotlin
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".view.FeedFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

*FeedAdapter.kt*

```kotlin
val DIFF_UTIL = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Photo>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Photo, newItem: Photo) = oldItem.id == newItem.id
    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Photo, newItem: Photo) = oldItem == newItem
}

class FeedAdapter : PagedListAdapter<Photo, FeedAdapter.ViewHolder>(DIFF_UTIL) {

    inner class ViewHolder(private val binding: PhotoCellBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(photo: Photo) {
            // Logs valid valid URLs as expected from 'photo.largeImageURL'.
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Debug photo ${photo.largeImageURL}")
            binding.postImage.setPostImage(photo.largeImageURL)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        return ViewHolder(PhotoCellBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        getItem(position)?.let { holder.bind(it) }
    }
}
```

*Glide.kt*

```kotlin
fun ImageView.setPostImage(image: String) {
    Glide.with(context)
        .load(image)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_content_placeholder)
        .error(R.drawable.ic_error)
        .into(this)
}
```

## Attempt Solution

1. **Hard code the parent root CardView `layout_height` in the *photo_cell.xml* RecyclerView item layout and set ConstraintLayout to `android:layout_height="match_parent"` instead of `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`.**

This is not ideal as it requires specifying the dimensions for different devices as opposed to the layout rendering based upon the image height dynamically with `wrap_content`.

*photo_cell.xml*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="500dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:translationZ="0dp">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/postImage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/photo_image_alt"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="@string/feed_image_ratio"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

2. **Programmatically set the layout width and height.**

This is not ideal because all of the attributes defined in the XML layout are overwritten.

*FeedAdapter.kt*

```kotlin
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val binding = PhotoCellBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false)
        binding.card.layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            // Sets the height to the display width to create a 1:1 aspect ratio.
            Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.widthPixels
        )
        return ViewHolder(binding)
    }
```

## Related Posts

- *[match_parent width does not work in RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30691150/match-parent-width-does-not-work-in-recyclerview)*
- *[View in RecyclerView does not match parent width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30251626/view-in-recyclerview-does-not-match-parent-width)*
- *[RecyclerView children match_parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45238053/recyclerview-children-match-parent)*

Comment: Follow This Link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55211279/recyclerview-in-constraintlayout-is-not-showing-properly

Comment: Thank you for the note @AndroidDeveloper. However, adding `app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"` per the linked post, did not fix the ImageView height rendering issue.

Comment: Why don't you use `wrap_content` for height for the ImageView ?

Comment: Great suggestion @NongthonbamTonthoi. I've tried `wrap_content` in the code in question above without success. Programmatically or hard-coding the layout size is still the only workaround despite implementing ConstraintLayout's dynamic sizing successfully in other applications like the [sample](https://github.com/AdamSHurwitz/CameraXFeed#-cameraxfeed) above.